# Giveaway commands does not save (Heroku) discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am making a giveaway command, but whenever I restart all dynos in heroku it seems the giveaway just froze(Never ends the giveaway) and when I do !gdelete {messageid} It says there is no giveaway for {messageid} any idea why and how to fix it. I have tried using quick.db but still the same and I am quite new to heroku and coding discord bot. Im using node.js

```
const { GiveawaysManager } = require("discord-giveaways");

const manager = new GiveawaysManager(bot, {
    storage: "./giveaways.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 10000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "#FF0000",
        reaction: ""
    }
})
bot.giveawaysManager = manager;
```

Heres the code

And heres the gstart command: https://pastebin.com/9tBjpVEY

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by Heroku, which doesn't store local files when you're not running the app. Every time you restart a dyno Heroku deletes everything and rebuilds it: that means that if you save your files locally when it restarts they'll get deleted.

To solve this issue you need either to switch to another service or to create some form of backup for your file.
You could also use a remote database, but I don't know how that could be implemented with the `discord-giveaways` package.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-giveaways oh ok thanks for help

Comment: If this solved your issue, please remember to mark the question as solved by accepting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think that it can be solved by doing this:

Instead of using quick.db, you can use quickmongo which just the same as quick.db and `discord-giveaways` also has an example of it. Although there is one change that you need to make. The example of quickmongo also shows a local way to store the files but instead of typing the localhost string, replace it with the MongoDB Compass connection string of your MongoDB cluster and give the new collection the same name which is `giveaways`.

In order to get the connection string, log in to your MongoDB account and create a cluster. After creating the cluster, click the connect button on the cluster and then select `Connect using MongoDB Compass`. From there you will see a connection string. Copy and paste that string in the place where there was the localhost string. Then replace `<password>` with your account's password which is your password with your username. Also, replace the `test` at the end with `giveaways` and you are good to go. After running the code, you would also see a collection named giveaways in the Collections Tab inside your cluster.

Example:

```
const db = new Database('connectionLink/giveaways');
db.once('ready', async () => {
    if ((await db.get('giveaways')) === null) await db.set('giveaways', []);
    console.log('Giveaway Database Loaded');
});
```